# Android MVP WeakRefrence

Tags: android, mvp, weak-references

In mvp we save that reference of an activity in a weak reference.
   `WeakReference<Activity> view = new WeakReference<Activity>(activity);`
If we lose the reference. can we get it back?

Answer (score 4):

If you lose the reference to your `Activity` it means the activity was garbage collected and it doesn't exist anymore. You can't get back what doesn't exist.

Ex. If this happens because of configuration change it means a new `activity` was created.

You need a way to attach the newly created view to the same presenter.

If you are looking for libraries to help you, take a look at [mosby](https://github.com/sockeqwe/mosby) and [nucleus](https://github.com/konmik/nucleus).

Comment: "You need a way to attach the newly created view" how to do so?
thx so much for your answer

Comment: @MethnaniBilel it's a complex problem to solve... take a look at mosby and/or nucles to see how they have solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be saving a reference to an `Activity` in `MVP` at all - doesn't matter if it's hard or weak!

I'm assuming you're storing this reference in the `Presenter`. To really decouple the layers you should create an interface that describes your `View` (`Activity`) and use it instead of the activity.

So you'd do:

```
public interface LoginView {
    displayUsernameError(String error);
    displayPasswordError(String error);
    openMainScreen();
}
```

Your `Activity` should implement the interface from above.

```
public class LoginActivity implements LoginView {
    ...
}
```

In your presenter you'd have:

```
class LoginPresenter {
    private LoginView mView;

    public LoginPresenter(LoginView view) {
         mView = view;
    }

    public onLoginButtonClicked(String username, char[] password) {
         ...
         mView.openMainScreen();
    }
}
```

Immediate benefits of doing this:

1. The different layers are really decoupled. You can change your `Activity` (say you decide to use `Fragments` instead) without touching your `Presenter`.
2. Your presenter is fully testable using `JUnit` only! No need to use anything fancy to verify your interactions are correct, just plain `Mockito` to mock the  `LoginView`.

One other point to note - are you sure you want your `Presenter` to outlive your `View`? There are some situations when that can't be avoided, but in most cases they have the same life span - when the `View` is destroyed the `Presenter` should be as well.

Comment: Your mView is a strong reference of LoginActivity.

Comment: "I don't think you should be saving a reference to an Activity in MVP at all - doesn't matter if it's hard or weak!" you do understand `private LoginView mView;` is already a reference, right?

Answer (score 0):

How did you set the reference in the first place?

You should be setting it with a setter method in Activity's onCreate.
This "setter" method is often called "attach" or "bind".

```
fun attach(view: View) {
   this.view = view
}
```

So when new Activity is created due to configuration change, it will set itself to the presenter again. Note that you might be dealing with a new instance of the presenter too. However, based on your question I believe you want to attach the newly created activity to the same instance of presenter. If you got your presenter scoped right, this will work for both cases :)